Using FluentAssertions how to check equivalency between two DataTables ignoring the column type?
There is two DataTables with almost the same structure, it is desired to check if they are equivalents:
// Arrange
var expected = new DataTable();
expected.Columns.Add("DISTANCE", typeof(double));
expected.Columns.Add("ANOMALY_TYPE_SCL", typeof(string));
expected.Columns.Add("O_CLOCK", typeof(string));
expected.Columns.Add("INTERNAL", typeof(string));
expected.Rows.Add(20.975, "MELO-MIFE", "07:06", "INT");
expected.Rows.Add(21.077, "MELO-MIFE", "06:57", "INT");
expected.Rows.Add(22.319, "MELO", "07:07", "INT");
expected.Rows.Add(34.657, "MELO", "03:45", "INT");

var actual = new DataTable();
actual.Columns.Add("DISTANCE", typeof(object));
actual.Columns.Add("ANOMALY_TYPE_SCL", typeof(object));
actual.Columns.Add("O_CLOCK", typeof(object));
actual.Columns.Add("INTERNAL", typeof(object));
actual.Rows.Add(20.975, "MELO-MIFE", "07:06", "INT");
actual.Rows.Add(21.077, "MELO-MIFE", "06:57", "INT");
actual.Rows.Add(22.319, "MELO", "07:07", "INT");
actual.Rows.Add(34.657, "MELO", "03:45", "INT");

// Act & Assert
actual.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected, options => options.AllowingMismatchedTypes());

following the documentation the options.AllowingMismatchedTypes() but the execution of the test keep returning the following result:
Expected property actual.Columns[0].DataType to be System.Double, but found System.Object.
Expected property actual.Columns[1].DataType to be System.String, but found System.Object.
Expected property actual.Columns[2].DataType to be System.String, but found System.Object.
Expected property actual.Columns[3].DataType to be System.String, but found System.Object.

With configuration:
- Use declared types and members
- Compare enums by value
- Compare tuples by their properties
- Compare anonymous types by their properties
- Compare records by their members
- Include non-browsable members
- Match member by name (or throw)
- Be strict about the order of items in byte arrays
- Without automatic conversion.

Adding the following exclusion did not work either:
actual.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected, options => options.AllowingMismatchedTypes().Excluding(su =>
    (su.Type == typeof(DataColumn)) && (su.Path.EndsWith("DataType"))));


If "actual" is object typed - then why not "expect" that?

AllowingMismatchedTypes seems to refer to the type of the DataTable itself, not the types of the columns. (See linked docs <==).
